# Пропорция между MAE и коэффициентом корреляции Пирсона

Tags: python, алгоритм, математика, теория-вероятностей

Есть критерий схожести двух выборок (отображен на рисунке), в формуле указаны коэффициенты, которые определяют пропорцию оценочных функций, говорится, что они зависят от дисперсии, я предположил, что это F-test, то есть отношение квадрата дисперсии двух выборок, но я думаю, что это неправильно, как может соотноситься оценочные функции?[image: Критерий схожести двух выборок]

Comment: Приведите источник, в котором приведена данная формула. Потому как даже само предназначение этой формулы не выглядит вразумительно-понятным.